# Antlr 4 creating Java Heap Size Out Of Memory issue

Tags: java, parse-tree, antlr4cs

I am trying to create ParseTree objects for a huge set of (really huge) java files using the Java7 grammar, but in the middle, getting an out of memory issue with GC overhead. I am cleaning up the ParseTree and Parser/Lexer after completing each file. When I looked at the memory analyzer, it is found that **org.antlr.v4.runtime.dfa.DFA[]** is taking 87% of the heap space. I have gone through some old bugs related to this but nothing really works for me. I am using Antlr version 4.7.

From the old bugs, I understand that clearing the DFA[] won't help. Are there any APIs being added for the cache eviction and to release resources efficiently?
thanks in advance.

Comment: We have just found a similar error with a similar fingerprint. prod]# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap spaceException in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - We are also doing a parsetree on 3m lines of code. Anyone seeing similar issue ?